# does not delete with jpql request

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

The method should delete all ads in a person by his id. it doesn’t give errors, I don’t understand how to make a debug to check what is wrong.

```
 public void deleteAllAdByPersonById(int id) {
        EntityManager em = FACTORY.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        Query query = em.createQuery("DELETE  FROM Ad a WHERE a.person.id = :id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        transaction.commit();
        em.close();    
    }
```

Person

```
@Entity
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "person_id")
    private int id;    
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull(message = "Name cannot be null")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE})
    private Set<Ad> ads = new HashSet<>();
```

Ad

```
    @Entity
    public class Ad {
 @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ad_id")
    private int id;
       ...
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "person_fk_id")
        private Person person;
```

Comment: You never execute your `Query`. You just create it, set the parameter...then end the transaction.

Comment: delete function shouldn't it be necessary to find and delete everything that is needed?

Comment: It's necessary to execute a `Query` for it to do something. It doesn't execute itself magically.

Comment: if I write em.remove (query); then i will remove em but not what i need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just had to write

```
query.executeUpdate();
```

after

```
query.setParameter("id", id);
```